# IE browser fires onchange event again when an observable property gets a new value

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have a web application where I am using Knockout js for client. I have a grid which has 3 columns, list price, discount and customer price. The list price get displayed in rounded values whereas discount and customer price needs to be displayed in 2 decimal places. Also, customer price should get auto-calculated if list price or discount changes.

To achieve this, I have onchange event on list price. Also I use, two observables, listPrice and displayedListPrice. List price to store unformatted value and displayedListPrice to store formatted value.

The following issue is in IE only - Inside the function I have a statement,
    this.displayedListPrice(format(this.ListPrice));

The above statement cause onchange event to fire again. How can I prevent that?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you got it to work, please post your solution as an answer, then mark that answer as accepted. This helps the StackOverflow ecosystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was gone for a while and didn't notice the comments from fellow users. 
Anyways, this is what I did -

```
<div class="clmn7" ><input class="number"  data-bind="uniqueName: true,value: displayedListPrice, event: {focus: pac.partsPricing.Part.prototype.onFocusListPrice , blur: pac.partsPricing.Part.prototype.listPriceChanged}, css: { pricechange : listPrice()!=masterListPrice(), nopricechange:listPrice()==masterListPrice()} , attr: { title: masterSPrice}, enable: viewModel.program().isEnabled() && status()!='Submitted' "/></div>
```

So, instead of using onChange event to capture the event and do processing, I used focus and blur events to do the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another event for the value binding, with something like that.

`<input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />`

You have the documentation here : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html